# Как открыть файл с именем переменной?

Tags: файлы, php

Добрый день,

вот я присваиваю переменной имя файла:

```
$file = "1.php";
```

Как открыть файл с именем переменной? Я пробовал делаю так:

```
$fp = fopen($file, "a+"); 
$ball= fgets($fp, 99); 
fclose($fp);
```

Но не получается. Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: А у вас файл 1.php существует? Какие ошибки падают? Что вы хотите из него прочитать? Может быть он пустой?

Answer (score 2):

> a+ Открывает файл для чтения и записи; **помещает указатель в конец файла**. Если файл не существует - пытается его создать.

зачем вам вообще a+ ?  чтобы прочитать первую строку вам нужно воспользоваться [fseek](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fseek.php).

Comment: спасибо за совет)
а проблему решил сам:)